# No se puede convertir un objeto DBNull en otros tipos

Tags: c#, sql, casting

estoy creando una aplicación en la cual se puedan hacer reservas, en el mapper de las propiedades les he pasado un método llamado "CargarPropiedades" en el cual le paso los datos como por ejemplo el tipo, etc, el problema es cuando le quiero pasar el usuario que ha dado de alta esa propiedad, lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
 private Propiedad CargarPropiedad (SqlDataReader r)
        {
var prop= new Propiedad();
prop.idPropiedad = Convert.ToInt32(r["idPropiedad"]);
//prop.usuario = new Usuario() { idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(r["idUsuario"])};
...
...
}
```

En el formulario a la hora de crear una propiedad lo que hago es hacer una variable de sesión

```
Usuario user = (Usuario)Session["Usuario"];
Propiedad prop = new Propiedad()
{
usuario = user,
nombre = txtNombre.Text,
...
...
...
}
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría muy agradecido, saludos.

Comment: La variable de sesión la hice para poder asignarle el usuario que da de alta a la propiedad, "usuario" es un atributo del dominio de "Propiedad" que  hace referencia a una clase llamada "Usuario"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se cual sera la propiedad que causa el problema con el DBNull pero basicamente deberias validar cuales columnas de la tabla permiten null y aplicar la validacion

```
private Propiedad CargarPropiedad (SqlDataReader r)
{
    var prop= new Propiedad();

    if(r["idPropiedad"] != DBNull.Value)
        prop.idPropiedad = Convert.ToInt32(r["idPropiedad"]);

    //resto codigo
}
```

la idea es validar si la columnas que tomas con el datareader es DBNull.Value

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta ya pude solucionar, mi problema era que había dado de alta propiedades sin haber hecho lo de la sesión antes entonces no me tomaba el id del usuario, hice update en la tabla desde SQL y ya no me dió más ese error.....creo que era por eso, el tema es que ahora funciona, saludos.